# Mount directory from another drive to Desktop/Videos

Tags: 16.04, automount

I use a ssd as system drive and want to outsource the video files because I have limited space on that ssd. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automount is done via the file /ect/fstab. The entry format is:

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
```

Device designations (/sdX) maybe used, but since they may change it is best to use UUID.

First copy your videos to the partition you want to use. Verify the copy was successful before deleting from your home directory. Next open gparted, select the drive and partition you want to use. Click on "info" in the partition menu at the top. Record the UUID of the partition you want to use.

Last, you will need root permissions to edit /etc/fstab. Add the following lines to the end of the file.

```
#Video partition mount
uuid=<UUID> /home/<user>/Videos ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Replace < UUID> with the UUID recorded earlier, and < user> with your user name. If the partition is on an external drive add `nofail` to the options so that boot doesn't crash if the drive isn't present. IF the partition isn't formatted ext4 correct that as needed.

Comment: So I need a seperate partion per directory? I'd prefer to have one partition for all my outsorced folders (e.g. videos, pictures, downloads) if possible.

Comment: In that case, mount the partition to an arbitrary point then replace your home folders with simlinks to the folders on the data partition.

Answer (score 1):

As ravery answered you can mount another drive as `~/Videos`

You can also mount the drive to an unused path in `/mnt`. Then bind mount directories from the second drive onto directories in `~/`

```
# Custom bind mounts
uuid=<UUID>      /mnt/UUID          ext4 defaults 0 2
/mnt/UUID/Videos /home/$USER/Videos none bind     0 0
/mnt/UUID/Music  /home/$USER/Music  none bind     0 0
```